# how to exclude some job in count by prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I have a prometheus query which is as below:

`100 * (count by(job, namespace, service) (up == 0) / count by(job, namespace, service) (up)) > 10`

and it is giving result

```
{job="kubernetes-pods"}
12.121212121212121
{job="kube-prometheus-kube-proxy", namespace="kube-system", service="kube-prometheus-kube-proxy"}  12.98
{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints"}   19
```

but in the result i would like to exclude

```
job="kube-prometheus-kube-proxy"
```

How do i do that ? I tried something like :

```
100 * (count by(job {job!=“kube-prometheus-kube-proxy”}, namespace, service) (up == 0) / count by(job {job!=“kube-prometheus-kube-proxy”},, namespace, service) (up)) > 10

and 

100 * (count by(job, namespace, service) {job!=“kube-prometheus-kube-proxy”} (up == 0) / count by(job, namespace, service) {job!=“kube-prometheus-kube-proxy”} (up)) > 10
```

and other options too.. But none of them work as expected... In the original count by query, what needs to be changed so that  it won't includ job job="kube-prometheus-kube-proxy" in result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter has to be written after metric name, which is `up` in this case. Thus:

```
100 * (
  count by(job, namespace, service) (up{job!="kube-prometheus-kube-proxy"} == 0)
  / 
  count by(job, namespace, service) (up{job!="kube-prometheus-kube-proxy"})
) > 10
```

Also, it seems my Prometheus does not like your stylish `“` quotes. I replaced them with typical `"`.